# Updating progress bar of another window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a new window and show completion on it. I'm using BackgroundWorker report event to do that. And it updates local properties of window which are bound to ProgressBar and TextBox.

This is triggered when progress Changes

```
    void copyBw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    //This is public method of child window which sets progress and text properties
        cpw.ChangeCompletion(e.ProgressPercentage, UserDefinedFileName);
    }
```

This is the method i'm  using to set the properties

```
public void ChangeCompletion(int Value, string file){
        Completion = Value;
        FileCopiedString += file;
    }
```

Below is my XAML

```
<ProgressBar Name="CopyProgress" Margin="0,41,-2,324" Width="634" Height="5" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Completion, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Label  Content="Please wait while files are getting copied ... " Margin="10,10,384,334" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <RichTextBox Name="CopyFileList" Margin="10,62,10,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="{Binding FileCopiedString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

The value of both properties get changed but won't report it to UI.

I've checked many threads but couldn't find the solution. Any pointers on this would be really helpful.

**Update:** When I set the property of ProgressBar Directly, (Without binding) then it works.
`CopyProgress.Value = Value;`

But this is not right and binding should happen. Now I've narrowed it down to Binding problem but I don't know where the mistake is.

Comment: Have you tried settings the [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) Property from the binding to `PropertyChanged`?

Comment: Are there any Binding errors in the output window?

Comment: did you set DataContext?

Comment: •No There is no binding error in output window. • I just tried UpdateSourceTrigger and its not working either. • I've set DataContext to the child window in constructor of it `this.DataContext = this;`

Comment: change Margin of progressbar..

Comment: I don't think margin is causing problem, I can resize the window and  check whether its updating or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've been able to resolve it. I think its a bit overkill but it worked.

I wasn't following MVVM. After I created a ViewModel and set that as default DataContext to View, it worked. When I tried to mix up with the ViewModel and View, eventhough it is supposed to work, it didn't.

View:

```
enter public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged{
public Window1(){   
ProgressBarViewModel pbvm = new ProgressBarViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = pbvm;
}}
```

ViewModel:

```
public partial class ProgressBarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged{
int _completion;
    public int Completion
    {
        get { return _completion; }
        set
        {
            _completion = value;
            Notify("Completion");
        }
    }

private string _fileCopied;
public string FileCopiedString
{
    get { return _fileCopied; }
    set
    {
        _fileCopied = value;
        Notify("FileCopiedString");
    }
}

public void ChangeCompletion(int Value, string file)
{
    Completion = Value;
    FileCopiedString = FileCopiedString + file;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void Notify(string name)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it. it is working for me.
XAML :

```
<ProgressBar Name="CopyProgress" Height="15" Maximum="10" Value="{Binding Completion}" Margin="0,26,0,220" />
    <Label  Content="Please wait while files are getting copied ... " Margin="10,10,384,334" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <RichTextBox Name="CopyFileList" Margin="12,60,41,12">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="{Binding FileCopiedString}"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

c#:

```
 public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    int _completion;
    public int Completion
    {
        get { return _completion; }
        set
        {
            _completion = value;
            Notify("Completion");
        }
    }

    private string _fileCopied;
    public string FileCopiedString
    {
        get { return _fileCopied; }
        set
        {
            _fileCopied = value;
            Notify("FileCopiedString");
        }
    }

    public void ChangeCompletion(int Value, string file)
    {
        Completion = Value;
        FileCopiedString = FileCopiedString + file;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void Notify(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I copy-pasted the same thing. Even after that it's not working.